# Force last job to run synchronously in laravel Queue

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-queue

I have implemented laravel queues and setup supervisor to monitor jobs execution. I have assigned 25 workers to my queue so that jobs can be processed concurrently,I want to force last job in the queue to process synchronously, let's say I dispatch 263 jobs so job #263 must be execute after 262 jobs successfully executed.

I have tried the solution to use `dispatchNow()` method on the last job then it will execute synchronously but It does not work.

Anybody have solution ?